# Streaming a video from Windows 7 laptop to Samsung TV

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, video, streaming

I am trying to setup my environment so that I can stream video from my Windows 7 laptop to my Samsung TV.

My WiFi router and laptop has 802.11n, the Samsung TV has Wifi support. However I find that the streaming quality is not that good; the video is choppy.

Would connecting one of the devices (either TV or laptop) directly into the router with an Ethernet cable make any difference?

I am thinking if the network speed is the bottleneck, putting one of them wired directly to the router would not make any difference, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic streaming is working?

You could try with videos of different bitrate and see where it starts becoming unacceptable to watch.

Just because your Laptop has 802.11n does not necessarily mean the throughput is good enough to stream video content. The bottleneck will always be the slowest device, and you didn't specify if your TV has n Wifi, too. Then again it depends on the router's position. For example, I can't stream videos from a NAS to my Macbook (which has n Wifi) from an n router that is less than 6m away.

So, my recommendation would be: Connecting **both TV and laptop** to Ethernet is probably the best option as the throughput here is rather constant and not depending on your location within the room. I have a NAS and a Samsung TV connected with Gigabit LAN and it works perfectly even with HD content.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you need a way to host your multimedia files (movies and songs), stored remotely at your Windows 7 laptop, on to your "Samsung Smart TV" via local network (wireless router).

Assuming both your smart TV as well as your Laptop is connected on the same network.

You might want to use "Serviio console" in order to achieve what I specified above. Serviio is easy to install, configure and is free to download. With Serviio you can easily host your multimedia files over the network or even across the internet (using port forwarding) without any lag.

http://www.serviio.org/download

Alternatively , you could use "Universal Media Server":

http://www.universalmediaserver.com/